# Выбор категории в dropDownList , yii2

Tags: php, yii2, dropdown

Нужно сделать чтобы в dropDownList был деревовидный список типа

Категория1

--Категория1.1

--Категория1.2

Категория2
....

Есть код, который формирует этот список, но в нем я могу выбрать только подкатегорию, а главную немогу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так вот вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы можна было выбрать и первую категорию .

Листинг метода поиска категории

```
 public static function getHierarchy()
     {
         $options = [];

         $parents = self::find()->where("parent_id=0")->all();

         foreach ($parents as $id => $p) {

             $children = self::find()->where('parent_id=:parent_id', ['parent_id' => $p->id])->asArray()->all();
             $child_options = [];

             foreach ($children as $child)
             {
                 $child_options[$child->id] = $child->name;
             }
             $options[$p->name] = ArrayHelper::map($children, 'id', 'name');
         }
         return $options;
     }
```

Comment: Селект кастомизирован с помощью какого нибудь js фрэймворка на подобие bootstrap или jquery, так што копайте в сторону где он инициализируеться, далее документация по нему, опции и профит.

Comment: «Категории» создаются с помощью [`<optgroup>`](https://webref.ru/html/optgroup) если не ошибаюсь, поэтому-то его и выбрать нельзя ... Здесь скорее нужно использовать стили, чтобы реализовать подобное.

Answer (score 1):

На optgroup нельзя сделать селект из-за особенностей html'a. Самое простое решение

```
.optionGroup {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}

.optionChild {
    padding-left: 15px;
}

<select multiple="multiple">
    <option value="0" class="optionGroup">Parent Tag</option>
    <option value="1" class="optionChild">Child Tag</option>
    <option value="2" class="optionChild">Child Tag</option>
</select>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892247/selectable-optgroup-in-html-select-tag

Comment: cheops, благодарю! может подскажешь, что-то не могу найти, как сниппет вставить...